# How to set all breakpoints on material ui?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on material-ui and wonder whether I can set all breakpoints at once.

Below code looks very redundant. Is there a simple way to do that?

```
<Grid xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12}>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: I really don't know about material-ui, but most of the time `xs={12}` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In material-ui, the breakpoint used matches the defined screen size or larger.

> Each breakpoint matches with a fixed screen width
>
> - xs, extra-small: 0px or larger
> - sm, small: 600px or larger
> - md, medium: 960px or larger
> - lg, large: 1280px or larger
> - xl, extra-large: 1920px  or larger

https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/

If you're wanting to target every break point, just specify the xs size and you'll be good.